# multiple cores single memory access bare metal

Tags: c, memory, shared-memory, bare-metal

i have the following code running on 2 bare metal A15 cores (only value is changed)

```
    #define MSMC_ADDR 0xc000080
int main(void) {

        *(unsigned int*) MSMC_ADDR = 0xACCCBBBB;
        printf("%d\n",*(unsigned int*)MSMC_ADDR);

    return 0;
}
```

my problem is simple.. i am unable to change the data from both cores because both will be trying to access the memory block.... so i end up with only 1 core being able to change that data.... is there any way i could free the MSMC_ADDR once change has been done so both the cores can access it at runtime?

p.s. i am using On chip memory

Comment: You should declare `MSMC_ADDR` as a `unsigned int`, it's not possible to change the value of a `#define` during runtime because it only exists as a pre-processor constant.

Comment: the #define is used to set the address and not the value

Comment: Oh I understand now, I wasn't aware of this feature, sorry.

Comment: `is there any way i could free the MSMC_ADDR...?` - You do not seem to allocate a block of memory starting at this address, so you obviously don't need to "free it". In fact, the `access bare metal` part in the title of your question implies that there is no memory management here in the application level, and even in the OS level (if you are running over some OS). It sounds like the only possible memory management is in the HW level, which you should not concern yourself with.

Comment: If you are unable to change the contents of this memory address via one of your cores, then check how you are initializing this core's HW (in particularly, the bus that connects this core to the shared memory device).

Comment: yes i think the problem is with the HW bus... ran 2 different addresses and got the same result

Comment: you need a cache flush. Try sys/bios api, there are functions for that bcache_wb, bcache_wb_inv, bcache_inv